# Topic of the Week Contest [Updated August 29]

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, contest

This is a quick way to expand the scope of the site and generate new questions and answers.

**How it works:** One topic will be designated each week. Each person who [asks a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize. The current topic is listed below.

**How to enter:** [Ask a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly. Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win a sci-fi item of your choice from your local Amazon (under $50). The question must not be closed or deleted to be eligible. *Users may only win a topic contest once a month.* Users will be informed of the month's topics in advance.

**Choosing the topic of the week:** If you have suggestions for a future topic, please leave them as answers to this post. Topics must be trackable with a tag, meaning that specific authors, books, television shows, movies and franchises are encouraged. Basically anything that currently has a tag is probably fair game. Topics will be chosen based on either their timely and increased notoriety or to expand the Sci-Fi's content and scope.

---

**Current Topic: INDEFINITE HIATUS**

At this moment and for the foreseeable future, I will not be able to run any Topic of the Week endeavors. That does not mean that the site can't have Topic of the Week contests, especially since people still seem very keen on them. These can still happen, they will just have to be run by you, the community. I pass along my power to you! That does mean that there will no longer be a prize awarded by Stack Exchange, which I hope isn't a massive deterrent.

**But why?!**

I apologize for not including this earlier; my haste caused me to not expand. My co-worker Laura [summed this up pretty well](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/the-end-of-a-contest-and-beginning-of-something-else) on the Cooking site, when their TOTW was discontinued.  For the *most* part, the reasons are the same. A $50 a week prize for the contest that results in-between 5-7 questions a week isn't that sustainable on our end. But the best thing, truthfully, is that Sci-Fi doesn't really *need* it as much as it did 8 months ago. The site is showing exponential growth and diversification, to the point where we on our end don't feel you need us nudging you along. Y'all are doing great on your own!

But you also aren't alone! If the community wants to keep going with the TOTW, then please do! It should just now be controlled organically from the community. And if the community needs advice or input from SE, please ping me!

---

**Completed Topics:**

- [The Hunger Games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games) (Jan 6-13), won by [thedaian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3101/thedaian)
- [Underworld](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underworld) (Jan 16-22), won by [DavRob60](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45/davrob60)
- [Star Trek: The Next Generation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) - The Next Level (Jan 23-29), won by [TangoOversway](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tangooversway)
- [Avatar: The Last Airbender](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender) (Jan 30-Feb 5), won by [Origami Robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2057/origamirobot)
- [Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phantom-menace) (Feb 6-12), won by [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/slytherincess)
- [The Walking Dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) (Feb 13-19), won by [Beofett](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1359/beofett)
- [Being Human](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/being-human) (Feb 20-26), won by [Kevin Howell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4355/kevin-howell)
- [Buffy the Vampire Slayer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy) seasons 1 & 2 (Feb 27-Mar 4), won by [Tony Meyer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer)
- [John Carter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-carter)/[Barsoom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barsoom) (Mar 5-11), won by [TangoOversway](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tangooversway)
- [Marvel's the Avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) (Mar 12-18), won by [Pureferret](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804/pureferret)
- [Robert A. Heinlein](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robert-a-heinlein) (Mar 19-25), won by [DVK](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk)
- [Farscape](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farscape) (Mar 26-Apr 1), won by [The Doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3383/the-doctor)
- [Game of Thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) (Apr 2-Apr 15), won by [DavRob60](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45/davrob60)
- [The Legend of Korra](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-korra) (Apr 16-Apr 29), won by [OghmaOsiris](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1109/oghmaosiris)
- [Video Games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) (Apr 30-May6), won by [Joe Wreschnig](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1030/joe-wreschnig)
- [Futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) (June 13-20), won by [DavRob60](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45/davrob60)

Comment: Does writing a question about the topic GUARANTEE an entry into the drawing? even if it gets closed and/or deleted?

Comment: We want to encourage good, quality questions, so if this contest allows closeable questions to be eligible, then we run the risk of getting a flood of bad questions. So a question has to remain open to be eligible. I will amend the post!

Comment: By "mass media", do you mean "film"? I don't see any book events there.

Comment: @TonyMeyer I mean "mass media," but in my haste/lazybrainness can only name the big movies coming out this year.

Comment: Heh. I was putting off reading Hunger Games till 2012. Guess it's time :)

Comment: It'd be great if you CHAOS folk could co-ordinate this across the sites (esp. movies, literature, here).  e.g. both *The Hobbit* and *Hunger Games* were proposed at literature.se (and both would likely be on-topic if movies.se starts doing this).  If these events create a lot of duplication, that's not as much of a win.

Comment: Is an ST:TNG topic week really needed?  Doesn't Trek get enough coverage as it is?

Comment: @TangoOversway That is being done in conjunction with the release of Star Trek: TNG on Blu-Ray, which I imagine is going to be a fairly big deal in the sci-fi community.

Comment: @BrettWhite: Okay, not being picky, but if it comes out on blu-ray, won't there be plenty of questions on it once people start watching it?

Comment: @TangoOversway This will also be done with a grant. The hope with a grant and also, sometimes, the topic-of-the-week contests is to seed the site with questions that people will be Googling for, thus leading them to this site.

Comment: @brett - Could you please link to the specific question that has won each drawing? Inquiring minds (ok, IDLE minds!) want to know.

Comment: @DVK Specific questions don't win. Each question you ask enters your name into a random drawing. If people want me to, I can affix questions to the names from this point on. OR we could make the win less random, perhaps based on question views?

Comment: @BrettWhite - You call. It was really just idle curiosity :)

Comment: Hi Brett - I've just figured out what the number next to the question means... I thought it (currently 1/30) meant this was the first question of thirty. But it's how you write dates on your planet. Suggest you replace with something that fits the rest of the known universe, e.g. 30 January. (More seriously: US date system is confusing for those not used to it.)

Comment: Why Buffy S1? I'm a fan and it would be great to see Buffy questions, but why then and why S1 only? S1 was, let's be honest, pretty crap, there were only 12 episodes, and it didn't have the buildup of the rich background story that we have now that we're in season 9.  *Being Human*, *ST:TNG*, *The Walking Dead* - none of these are/were season specific.

Comment: @TonyMeyer I am planning on doing all of Buffy throughout the year. It makes sense to me to focus on season 1 first. Perhaps season 1-2? And trust me, I know season one is crap. You don't have to convince me of such.

Comment: @Beofett It's about that season of Buffy. So only questions about that season's episodes count. Not general mythos ones, not ones about the movie. It would work the same way the Star Trek: TNG topic week worked, where people could only ask questions about the episodes on the Blu-Ray that just came out. And I know the title of *every* Buffy episode and what season it is from. *Every one*. The logistics don't seem hard to me at all.

Comment: I didn't notice that TNG was only about three episodes.  It seems odd, but maybe there are some great Buffy S1 questions.  Maybe.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that we are promoting quantity over quality here. What if you got the score of the question (at the time the period ended) as the number of entries? So if someone asks an awesome 50-vote question, they get 50 entries?

Comment: @TonyMeyer I'm not concerned so much about quantity over quality because, honestly, the quantity so far hasn't been overwhelming. It's been just whelming. And I think there is some Stack hesitancy about using upvotes to determine winners (something about sock puppets, maybe? Is that crazy?). I'm up for changing the method of winning, and having quality be a factor, just have to figure out what the right method is.

Comment: *"If you have suggestions for a future topic, please leave them as answers to this post."* Vote to close. This is a [list question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-should-we-handle-any-list-questions). :)

Comment: I have to agree abut the *lack of awareness*. I don't usually read Meta, and didn't know there *was* a contest until just seeing someone mention the Heinlein week contest... Maybe a banner on the Main page?

Comment: To fix the issue of movies releasing on the penultimate day of the Topic of the Week, maybe we should have these run from Tuesday to Monday instead of Sunday to Saturday?

Comment: Current topic: A Game of Thrones.  Tag with [game-of-thrones] to participate. However, Season 2 actually coincides with "A Clash of Kings". Are eligible questions only related to the show, or do questions about the books count? If so, should "A Clash of Kings" questions be tagged "game-of-thrones"? That seems wrong to me.  What about later books? Would "a-song-of-ice-and-fire" be a better tag choice?

Comment: @Beofett It's specifically about the TV show, since that's what has just debuted and that's what will, theoretically, get us views.

Comment: @BrettWhite Given that Season 2 of the TV show covers with almost perfect faithfulness (if Season 1 is any indication), it seems that tagging questions that are directly relevant to book 2 with the name of book 1 simply to indicate that the person wants to enter a contest seems inappropriate to me... is there a better method of tagging we could use? Like "Game-of-thrones-show"?

Comment: @Beofett Sounds like a separate question for meta. Because from my viewpoint, it seems very confusing for a person who has never read the book to intuit that their question about season 2 should be tagged with anything OTHER than the name of the show they watch. Seems very complicated.

Comment: [Meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/how-should-game-of-thrones-questions-tied-to-the-tv-show-be-tagged) posted.

Comment: @BrettWhite shouldn't you have a link to the actual users' profiles instead of just their names so poeple could check out other questions that they might have?

Comment: @BrettWhite Shall we close this meta question and start a fresh one so we have a clean slate of suggested topics?

Comment: If you want another example of something that'd get as much action as video-games, I think "Marvel movies" would be hot right about now... ;)

Comment: @Keen We still haven't had a [Discworld](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1180) week. We barely have any [tag:discworld] content, even though it's one of the biggest written SF universes.

Comment: I think one of the reasons for video games getting so many questions is the broadness of the category. Usually the questions (that I've seen) specify a lot more. To increase questions maybe alternate between broad categories and specific ones (ex. broad-short stories, specific-Fringe)

Comment: Hey Brett - you are asking for ideas - so why haven't you used my *meta theme* idea? (At least, until now - I guess Video Games is the first one - perhaps that at least partially explains its success?)

Comment: Brett, I'm a mod on movies.SE.  Would you mind if I stole the template of this (with attribution, of course) for a similar idea we're pushing around on our site? :)

Comment: @TylerShads Please do! Anything to help communities grow and expand!

Comment: Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Should a mod get rid of the answers that have been accepted/gone past their suggested dates?

Comment: Do we have a topic for any of the coming weeks?

Comment: @BrettWhite: has this stopped, now?

Comment: @Wikis I just updated the post with information.

Comment: @BrettWhite: ok, but there goes the robots and disasters prize...

Comment: @BrettWhite - I don't think it's out of line to ask for a basic explanation as to why SE won't support TOTW on SFF any further. Why is this happening? Does SFF have any SE liaison/representative now, as it sounds like you're stepping out of the picture? This has all just been very abrupt, is all. Thanks :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Added more explanation! Sorry for the abruptness, but please don't take it to mean that I'm stepping out of the picture. I'm very much in the picture, it's just that I'm in a lot of sites' pictures right now. I am still here when Sci-Fi needs me, it's just that you guys are an incredibly strong, popular and successful community and you don't need as much assistance as other sites :)

Comment: @BrettWhite -- Thanks so much for the explanation. It makes sense. :)

Comment: Would it be out of line to propose a new, community driven way of picking a new topic, perhaps of the month to make it easier to maintain. Or do you not want the waters muddied if this feature returns (for whatever reason)?

Comment: @Pureferret I think that's a great idea, as long as the community has someone who can monitor it and anoint a "winner" (although without a prize, I don't think a winner is necessary? Up to y'all to decide)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a specific franchise, I'm thinking of some kind of meta theme, e.g.:

- robots
- disaster sci-fi
- robots causing disasters :)

The list is endless!

Comment: So long as it involves *Robots* and *Disaster* I'm in!

Comment: What about time traveling robots?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: **I need your clothes, your boots and your motorcycle.**

Comment: @wikis **I need your Questions, your Answers and your Reputation.**

Answer (score 6):

Awards, e.g.:

- [The Hugos](http://www.thehugoawards.org/)
- [The Nebulas](http://www.sfwa.org/nebula-awards/)
- [World Fantasy Awards](http://www.worldfantasy.org/awards/)
- [John W. Campbell Memorial Award](http://www.sfcenter.ku.edu/campbell.htm)
- [Academy Awards](http://www.oscars.org/) (if scifi/fantasy films get nominated)
- [Emmys](http://www.emmys.com/) (if scifi/fantasy shows get nominated)

This could either be broad (questions related to any of the nominees in a week before the award was given) or narrow (questions related to the winner(s) in a week after the award was given).

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to see some other topics that aren't so narrow and cover a wide range of works that we don't see much of.  For instance:

- Classic SF Film (includes *Forbidden Planet*, *Metropolis*, *2001: A Space Odyssey*, and a slew of other films, including B movies)
- Pulp authors/Golden age (includes Heinlein, Asimov, and all the others -- we see them, but not much of them)
- Pre/Proto SF&F (includes *Frankenstein*, Jules Verne, H.G. Wells, Edgar Allan Poe, *Castle of Otranto*, *MacBeth* for examples)

Answer (score 5):

Firefly would be another great addition. It just isn't covered well enough here, although it does have a few questions...

Answer (score 4):

[Total Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_%282012_film%29) would be a good one!

Answer (score 3):

One major series that has hardly been touched here is the Disc World series. It even was merged into this site a few weeks into the beta. This should be a topic for the site.

Comment: There are already vibrant Discworld communities out there. It's hard to compete with them: all the questions have already been asked and answered elsewhere. If we can get questions, and good answers, then that would be a huge boost for the site.

Answer (score 3):

A series of [Watchmen prequels](http://www.wired.com/underwire/2012/02/exclusive-before-watchmen/) was just announced.  This might be a good topic as the release of the first issues approaches.

Comment: Oh yes, noted. Big one. Big one.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to encourage niche topics, how about

- [Video Games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games)

As you can see, most questions with that tag are related to video games, that were created to an already existing franchise (Star Wars), which is already covered, simply for being a scifi/fantasy universe.

This is a bit sad, because many (non-spin-off) video-games offer quite interesting scifi *and* fantasy stories (from the top of my head, *Monkey Island*, *Half Life*, *Doom* (which spun off a couple books AFAIK), *arCraft, and so forth).

I once asked a [doom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom) question which received minimal attention, perhaps because the community is so focussed on the big mainstream works that are published via classical channels like film or books.

My point is: Lot of potential here that hardly anyone notices. Maybe the right thing for TotW.

Comment: [gaming.se] is the hot site in the network at the moment. A game-related topic could draw in a lot of visitors if we advertise there.

Comment: We like questions about gaming lore... bring them! (if you want)

Answer (score 2):

Ursula Le Guin? (I'm just suggesting that to get extra rep from my SO who's a fan :)))

Answer (score 2):

- *Walking Dead* returns to AMC in a couple of weeks.
- [*Game of Thrones*](http://hbowatch.com/hbo-series-premiere-schedule/) returns on April 1.

Answer (score 2):

The Work of HP Lovecraft and the Cthulhu Mythos could do with some attention.

Answer (score 2):

How about [zombie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie) week? Featuring questions about all incarnations of zombie lore (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

[Underworld: Awakening](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1496025/) is coming out in 2 weeks (friday, the 20 January 2012), so a [Underworld series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_%28film_series%29) week seems appropriate.

Comment: Great! I will schedule that one next, if all goes according to plan.

Comment: @BrettWhite So you are planning to do it the week *before* the release? The week following the release wouldn't be better? (FYI, I'm not planning to see it on theater)

Comment: We could run it Wednesday to Tuesday, so it captures lead up, opening weekend, and the first part of the week after.

Answer (score 1):

[Game of Thrones](http://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/index.html) Season 2 starts airing on the 15th April (presumably in the US) according to IMDB.

Answer (score 1):

If the site had existed when *LOST* was airing, I imagine it would have been pretty popular here.

I think it would be worth adding more *LOST* content - when I've been researching answers, I've found that the existing content is generally fairly low-quality.  In particular, there's a lot of material to be found that isn't up-to-date - it's speculation that hasn't been updated since the series ended.

There's a lot of material to draw from: other than the TV episodes there were regular podcasts, some 'webisodes', the DVD extras, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the works of [Gerry Anderson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson#Gerry_Anderson_productions) would be a good topic. There is plenty of material and it could add a whole new group of visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Vote this answer up if you also started feverishly trying to remember/google a Sci-Fi or Fantasy work titled "HIATUS" upon reading today's update :)

P.S. More on topic, I think **Lem** and **Zelazny** are heavily under-asked.

Answer (score 1):

### Philip K.Dick

This would be a good topic, on par with out recent Heinlen one. It would cover the upcoming Total Recall movie, and all the past novels and adaptations.

Answer (score 1):

#### Supernatural - Season Eight

..is airing soon (in 75 days) and may be it's last. Would be a good time to give the show some focus, and we know well enough in advance to prepare fore it.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised **[Doctor Who](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_who)** has not been added here. A new series is starting and it appears to be at a peak of popularity. This would certainly attract more people.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions, e.g.

- [WorldCon](https://chicon.org/)
- [ComicCon](http://www.comic-con.org/cci/)

Behind-the-scenes/fandom questions are on-topic here, so there could potentially be good questions about these events (although it would take work to avoid ones that were specifically about the 2012 events).

Answer (score 0):

Season 1 of *[American Horror Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Horror_Story)* was very popular, and the information about Season 2 coming out seems to be generating a fair amount of interest.  I don't know if a date for Season 2 has been announced yet, but this has the potential to draw a fair amount of new traffic.

Comment: I really loved *AHS* and thought it was over-the-top in a fabulous way. It came full circle, you know? But is it sci-fi or fantasy? As much as I think it's a clever and chilling show, I have to say I think its genre is horror.

Comment: @Slytherincess I don't think horror and scifi are mutually exclusive. The fact that the dead come back as ghosts firmly puts it in the realms of scifi/fantasy. If being a horror title puts it off topic, the "Alien" franchise, and countless other scifi titles would be off topic.

Comment: Have there been questions here about *American Horror Story*? What aspects of *AHS* do you find to be sci-fi or fantasy, as opposed to horror/paranormal? :)

Comment: @Slytherincess As I said, I don't feel they are mutually exclusive, so "as opposed to" is an inappropriate term. I believe I already mentioned the *ghosts*. How are vampires and werewolves scifi, but ghosts aren't?  And whether or not there are any questions yet is completely moot, since the whole point of this promotion is *to draw new traffic*.

Comment: Please note as well that we have a [horror] tag, with a fair number of questions (including Buffy questions).

Comment: That's fine! I was just curious as to your personal thoughts on it, but I suppose that's not appropriate for comments anyway. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I'll be back in chat tomorrow. If you're around, we can discuss it further there :)

Comment: That would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

### Roleplaying games

There are extensive novels, worlds and histories to most of the D&D worlds, as well as stories that go with many other mainstream roleplaying systems, like World of Darkness, Mouseguard, and various others.

It could tie in quite well with the release of D&D Next, whenever that is.

Answer (score 0):

**[Transformers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers)**, anyone?

There is a huge amount of material and it will help draw in new fans.

Answer (score 0):

## R.A. Salvatore, Mercedes Lackey, Anne/Todd McCaffrey

Prolific writers with lots of material. I want more fantasy. Icewind Dale anyone? Spine of the World; Hawk brothers; Crystal Singer and brain/brawn ships... drow elves, griffons, companions, fire-lizards...

Comment: Currently this thread is dead. I'm in the process of revamping/restarting this contest, [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/do-we-still-want-a-topic-of-the-week-month).

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure that *Harry Potter* needs help with getting more questions, or if a website is "mass media", but ...

Presumably [Pottermore](http://www.pottermore.com/) will go out of private beta at some point this year.

Comment: We don't really need a **contest** for that - just a "honoris causa" grant. We all know who's gonna win anyway, and she doesn't need a contest to encourage tons of great questions :)

Comment: I think that *Harry Potter* is a totally legitimate topic, especially if *Star Trek* is allowed, Blu-Ray or not. *Deathly Hallows 2* just came out on Blu-Ray too, not long ago. I'm not saying this because Potter is my thing, but I know one goal is to attract more users to the site. *HP* might make a good gateway for that. Just my two cents! :)