# GRANT: Star Trek: TNG - The Next Level on Blu-Ray

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

The release of **[Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Next Level](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064NLQYG)** on Blu-Ray gives us an opportunity to capitalize on some sci-fi excitement and hopefully draw new users to the site.

So I propose:

- 5 users with *the highest-rep of the month* at the time of grant's end (which can be viewed by clicking on the "users" and then "month" tab on the main page) will receive a copy of **Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Next Level** on Blu-Ray. **Note** that we are not giving away Blu-Ray players, so make sure you can play this disc.
- The recipients will be encouraged to **ask thoughtful questions** about the **specific episodes on the Blu-Ray**. We already have a ton of Star Trek: TNG questions on the site, but some about these particular episodes would hopefully drive traffic to the site. The episodes on the Blu-Ray are:

  - 1x01: *[Encounter at Farpoint](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint)*
  - 3x17: *[Sins of the Father](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sins_of_the_Father)*
  - 5x25: *[The Inner Light](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Inner_Light)*
- Blogging would also be encouraged.

Please answer below with your **username**.

The recipients will be chosen on **Tuesday, January 24th at 4:00 PM EST/21:00 UTC**.

---

**NOTE:** These episodes of Star Trek: TNG will be part of the next [**Topic of the Week Contest**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-1-13). This is running separately from the Grant.

Comment: Good Luck everyone! I intend to hold out for when the whole series comes out.

Comment: The Inner Light is an amazing episode. I'll wait til I have a Blu-Ray player, though.

Comment: I'm morally opposed to Worf-centric episodes, so I cannot in good conscience enter.

Comment: Not to be picky, but the way the points 1 and 2 are phrased, it sounds like the highest rep of the month at the grant's end gets the blu-ray and then those who get it are encouraged to ask questions about those episodes - as opposed to the point that one has to ask questions on those topics to be eligible for the blu-ray.

Comment: You don't have to ask questions on those topics to be eligible for the Blu-Ray. I don't believe that is anywhere in the post.

Comment: @Jeff - why are you morally opposed?

Comment: @DVK I just don't like the 'Proud Warrior Race Guy'.  Worf was possibly the least offensive of them, but I still wasn't a fan.

Answer (score 0):

Jack B Nimble

(Jack be quick to put his name in first.)

Answer (score 0):

DavRob60
and 22 characters....

Answer (score 0):

Beofett

I've been wanting to introduce my wife to ST:TNG for years!

Answer (score 0):

TangoOversway

(You can call me Tango -- everyone else does.)

Answer (score 0):

DVK

"body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 3"