# GRANT: Avatar: The Last Airbender - The Promise part 1

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promotional-grant

["The Promise"](http://www.midtowncomics.com/store/dp.asp?PRID=Avatar%20The%20Last%20Airbender_1159293) is the canon, graphic novel follow-up to the **[Avatar: The Last Airbender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_last_airbender)** series. It's release coincidentally lines up with next week's Avatar-themed [Topic of the Week](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-1-23) contest.

So I propose:

- Interested users will receive a copy of the **Avatar: The Last Airbender - The Promise part 1** graphic novel. Interested users need only reply to this with their username; the **first 5 users** to do so will receive the graphic novel *(I am making this grant exempt from rep because of the tight turnaround; I want to start ordering these ASAP instead of waiting a week for people to volunteer)*
- The recipients can **ask thoughtful questions** about the graphic novel at any time, and they may use the graphic novel to inspire questions for the Topic of the Week contest (between January 30th and February 5th).
- The entire **Avatar: The Last Airbender** canon is fair game for the Topic of the Week contest, so if you do not receive this graphic novel from Stack Exchange, you may still ask questions about the TV series and be eligible to win.
- Blogging would also be encouraged.

Please answer below with your **username**.

The first 5 recipients will be sent copies of the graphic novel.

---

UPDATE 1/26/12: Grant is closed!

Comment: I would do this in a heartbeat, but I already ordered it.

Comment: Now I feel lonely being the only applicant.

Answer (score 1):

Keen

...is wondering when Brett's going to realize that answers have a minimum character limit. :3

Comment: Never, because seeing what you guys come up with is always hilarious. MWAH HA HA.

Answer (score 0):

DavRob60

Answer (score 0):

Pureferret: The last queestionbender