# How should Game of Thrones questions tied to the TV show be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, contest

Since the Game of Thrones *show* is now [Topic of the Week](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-apr-2#comment3913_1138), I have a question/issue with how the questions should be tagged.

In order to be eligible for the contest, questions need to be tagged [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones).  However, Season 2 is based off of *A Clash of Kings*, which is book 2, and distinct from book 1 of A Song of Ice and Fire, *A Game of Thrones*.

If the question itself is applicable to both Season 2 of *Game of Thrones*, the TV series, and *A Clash of Kings*, book 2 of A Song of Ice and Fire, but *not* book 1 of A Song of Ice and Fire, *A Game of Thrones*, shouldn't we avoid using the [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) tag?

Would it be better to use something like [game-of-thrones-show](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones-show), or would that create more confusion?

Comment: I'd say it'd be better to use a "song-of-ice-fire" tag. Don't know if one exists, though. It applies to the show and the books, though, so it would fix the tagging issue you mention.

Comment: @GabeWillard It does exist.  However, as Brett White pointed out, viewers of the TV show may not be familiar with that title, and it may be confusing to the very new users we are trying to attract.

Comment: Hmm. Valid point. I don't know, then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Our options:

### Media/Meta Tags

For anything related to the show, tag them [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) and [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv). The [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) (which is the current tag) could still be used as well.

For anything related to the books, tag them [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire), [book-name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-name) (so [a-game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-game-of-thrones) for the first book), and [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) or [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel).

### Sub-tags

For anything related to the show, tag them [game-of-thrones-show](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones-show) (and possibly [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire)).

For anything related to the books, tag them [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) and [book-name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-name) (again [a-game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-game-of-thrones) for the first book). This make [a-game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-game-of-thrones) very similar-looking but actually very different from [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones), which is unfortunately complex.

### Deciding

This comes down to media/meta tags, yet again. We haven't made a collective decision to burninate them, and I'm of the opionion that they may actually serve some purpose within the scope of this site, so I'm more partial to the former option.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Ian's answer, I'd nominate the [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) and [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) combination of the TV show and leave [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) solo for the books.  Keeping it simple makes it easier for people, newbies and oldbies alike, to keep them tagged consistently.

Anecdotal evidence: I've read all the books and only just started watching the TV show, but I still call the series Game of Thrones.