# TV and TV Series Tag Cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Based upon [this meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/tag-disclaimer-it-should-only-be-used-when-not-immediately-clear), it seems there's a fairly decent consensus that [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) and [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) have not been used consistently.

Original discussion supported the idea that [media tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc) are bad in general, but there might be some specific uses for some of them.

Later discussion had [some support for specific uses](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/how-should-game-of-thrones-questions-tied-to-the-tv-show-be-tagged) of [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv).

However, [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), and its synonym, [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series), appear to have been used to mean everything from "I'm only interested in answers relating to this title on TV (i.e. no answers from books/movies/comics)" to "I once saw this movie on TV" to "I have a question about something that is on TV, but I'm also interested in answers that come from books/movies/video games/comics".

I suggest we remove [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) from any question that is clearly *not* using that tag to exclude other media (i.e. any question that clearly is open to answers from other media, including movies shown on TV; any question that is on a title where TV is already implicit, such as *Babylon-5*; or where a tag to exclude non-tv sources would simply not make sense).

Per a [suggestion from Keen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/conversation/tv-tag-cleanup), I'd like to first compile a list of all questions we think should be cleaned up.  Please feel free to add to this list as you see fit.

Comment: This sort of got dropped.  I added [tag:featured] to highlight it.

Comment: @Keen Thanks!  No one else chimed in, and I lost track of it.  I'll go through some more this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

- [How did the Suryanshi come to know about death of "Maha Guru" faster than Shaktimaan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14151/how-did-the-suryanshi-come-to-know-about-death-of-maha-guru-faster-than-shakti)
- [Completion of "Dark Angel" storyline?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/942/completion-of-dark-angel-storyline)
- [Why doesn't Rogue have super strength and the ability to fly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7009/why-doesnt-rogue-have-super-strength-and-the-ability-to-fly) (the accepted answer contains information from films and comics)
- [Why did Ambassador Jeffrey Sinclair not want Garibaldi to join him and others on War Without End mission?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29311/why-did-ambassador-jeffrey-sinclair-not-want-garibaldi-to-join-him-and-others-on)
- [Why did Merlin not heal his fatigue with magic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29328/why-did-merlin-not-heal-his-fatigue-with-magic)
- [Why was the Superman's symbol an *English* letter "S"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/why-was-the-supermans-symbol-an-english-letter-s) (this is tagged dc-comics as well, so it does not appear to be tagged [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) to eliminate other media).
- [What do The Flash's earpiece emblems do?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16479/what-do-the-flashs-earpiece-emblems-do) (same as previous)
- [Who or what sent the Orb back in time in "Brisco County Jr."?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28668/who-or-what-sent-the-orb-back-in-time-in-brisco-county-jr)
- [Is Time travel in "Star Trek: Enterprise" totally illogical?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/is-time-travel-in-star-trek-enterprise-totally-illogical)
- [Who else was at Hawkman's funeral besides the five speaking characters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20693/who-else-was-at-hawkmans-funeral-besides-the-five-speaking-characters)
- [Who are Blakes's 7?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/778/who-are-blakess-7)
- [What was the purpose of what happened to Trip in the last episode?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13530/what-was-the-purpose-of-what-happened-to-trip-in-the-last-episode)
- [Why did Major Nelson need to hide Jeannie from Dr. Bellows?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26377/why-did-major-nelson-need-to-hide-jeannie-from-dr-bellows)
- [How could the Picard Maneuver confuse sensors from the Warp Era?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25136/how-could-the-picard-maneuver-confuse-sensors-from-the-warp-era)
- [What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-was-the-robots-name-in-lost-in-space)
- [In Supernatural, why do the brothers not give more people anti-possesion tattoos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11391/in-supernatural-why-do-the-brothers-not-give-more-people-anti-possesion-tattoos)
- [What was Shepherd Book's past in Firefly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-was-shepherd-books-past-in-firefly)
- [Witchblade - watch the film before the TV series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23567/witchblade-watch-the-film-before-the-tv-series) (I'm somewhat undecided about this one...)
- [How did Sweet the demon lose?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-did-sweet-the-demon-lose)
- [Why were Ferengi unknown to 24th century Starfleet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-were-ferengi-unknown-to-24th-century-starfleet)
- [Why didn't the Earth & Vulcan battle cruisers engage the Xindi SuperWeapon and Reptilian ship?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22355/why-didnt-the-earth-vulcan-battle-cruisers-engage-the-xindi-superweapon-and-r)
- [How did the Borg come to know about Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/how-did-the-borg-come-to-know-about-earth)
- [How did the Sphere Builders build the Spheres?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/how-did-the-sphere-builders-build-the-spheres)
- [What is the law regarding magic in the BBC TV show Merlin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/what-is-the-law-regarding-magic-in-the-bbc-tv-show-merlin)
- [Why was command of USS Enterprise NCC-1701 given to Christopher Pike from Kirk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21811/why-was-command-of-uss-enterprise-ncc-1701-given-to-christopher-pike-from-kirk)
- [Were there multiple resistance groups in This is Not My Life, or just one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/were-there-multiple-resistance-groups-in-this-is-not-my-life-or-just-one)
- [Shouldn't Terry's younger brother have the same genetic traits as him?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15921/shouldnt-terrys-younger-brother-have-the-same-genetic-traits-as-him)
- [How safe is a person from evil spirits if he is at sea or on a salt lake?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/how-safe-is-a-person-from-evil-spirits-if-he-is-at-sea-or-on-a-salt-lake)
- [Does Lois Lane Know Who Superman Is (In Any Versions or Reboots)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12363/does-lois-lane-know-who-superman-is-in-any-versions-or-reboots)
- [When was Superman's first use of heat-vision?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/when-was-supermans-first-use-of-heat-vision)
- [David Lister is the last human being in the Universe. What happened to the rest of the human race?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20727/david-lister-is-the-last-human-being-in-the-universe-what-happened-to-the-rest)
- [Suggested starting place for Ghost in the Shell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20628/suggested-starting-place-for-ghost-in-the-shell)
- [What was Sarah Bartowski's nee Walker birth name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/what-was-sarah-bartowskis-nee-walker-birth-name)
- [Was Number 6 John Drake?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/was-number-6-john-drake)
- [What was the point of trying to escape after first contact with Q?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/what-was-the-point-of-trying-to-escape-after-first-contact-with-q)
- [In Star Trek: Enterprise, why did the repair station kidnap Mayweather for brain-based processing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/in-star-trek-enterprise-why-did-the-repair-station-kidnap-mayweather-for-brain)
- [Who was behind the R3S6 droid from the Republic's side?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18582/who-was-behind-the-r3s6-droid-from-the-republics-side)
- [Why, and how, was the island protected in Lost?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/lost-the-island-protection)
- [What is Sonic the Hedgehog's maximum running speed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/what-is-sonic-the-hedgehogs-maximum-running-speed)
- [How many times did Mom and the Professor actually date?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18234/how-many-times-did-mom-and-the-professor-actually-date)
  -

Comment: I'll continue to add to the list as I have time.

Comment: Made it a CW.  Anyone can add to the list as they have time. :)

Comment: @Keen - I know that CW in theory is supposed to be there for "anyone can edit" purpose on CW, but I've always been curious if there is any stats showing that it was evere useful for that (e.g. how many edits were made on CW posts by users with reputation below what is necessary to edit, at the time of editing). Any idea if that was ever disussed on Meta.SO?

Comment: I think media tags should stay and should be encouraged on [tag:story-identification], as quite a few people are interested only in some media and it's an obvious search criterion. [With hindsight, I think we should have split the story-identification tag](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/630/rename-the-story-identification-tag), but the community is rather against, so let's at least have [tag:story-identification]+([tag:short-story]|[tag:novel]|[tag:comics]|[tag:movie]|[tag:tv-series]|…).

Comment: @Gilles One thing I noticed so far is that a lot of the ones with [tag:tv] also have [tag:story-identification], however, many start with "I once saw this movie on TV...". It feels a bit ambiguous to tag something TV when it may have been a movie that re-aired on TV (or it could have been a made-for-tv-movie).

Comment: @Beofett [tag:tv] vs [tag:tv-series] is a different issue. I suspect we should split [tag:tv] into [tag:movies] and [tag:tv-series]. [I guess I've changed my mind](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/remove-the-tv-series-tag/1504#1504). As I'm mostly a reader, I'll let movie and series watchers decide.

Comment: @Gilles I like both of those suggestions quite a bit (combining Story ID with an appropriate media tag, and splitting [tag:tv] into [tag:movies] and [tag:tv-series]). Do you feel that media tags should be discouraged elsewhere (excepting Story ID and the exclusion-by-media I described in my question above)? If we split [tag:tv] into [tag:movies] and [tag:tv-series], does that include eliminating [tag:tv] as the end result?