# Futurama Week + Q&A Event on July 11th!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

SciFi.SE has partnered with Comedy Central to promote [*Futurama's*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama) upcoming season. We're declaring *Futurama* the topic of the week for the next week and, after that, we're launching a special *Futurama* minisite that will tie into a Q&A event! Awesome!

Bye!

Wait, huh? Oh! You want me to de-vague all of that vague stuff I just said? Sure!

---

***FUTURAMA* WEEK**

We're going to expand our *Futurama* content and prepare for the show's season premiere on June 20th by declaring **June 13th-20th *Futurama* Week**! All the normal [Topic of the Week](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138) rules apply (in fact, the [TOTW post will be updated](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138) to include *Futurama* Week). For those of you new to the ol' SciFi.SE TOTW format, here's an abridged version of the rules:

**How it works:** Each person who asks a *Futurama* question will be eligible to win a prize.

**How to enter:** Ask a question about *Futurama*, and tag it with [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win a sci-fi item of your choice from your local Amazon (under $50). The question must not be closed or deleted to be eligible.

**Dates: *Futurama*** week begins on Wednesday June 13th at 12:00 am EST/4:00 UTC and lasts until Wednesday June 20th at 11:59 pm EST/Thursday June 21st at 3:59 UTC. Yes, this "week" spans 8 days.

---

***FUTURAMA* MINISITE**

On June 27th, we will launch an official *Futurama* Stack Exchange minisite that will collect all of the [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) questions in one location, as well as some other goodies. 
The name of this site is TBD (you can [suggest a name for the site here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHdZWHg3Z2dZaFQtS285c2tSeWRwcUE6MQ#gid=0), but just know that Stack Exchange will own the name if it is used).

**Update :** The name of this site is [Answerama](http://answerama.com/).

see : [Answerama, the Futurama mini-site, is live!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/answerama-the-futurama-mini-site-is-live)

---

**LIVE *FUTURAMA* Q&A EVENT**

As revealed in a [press release on June 2nd](http://blog.zap2it.com/frominsidethebox/2012/07/futurama-live-cast-and-eps-will-answer-fan-questions-in-live-stream.html), the cast and creators of *Futurama* will take part in a live question and answer session. Between 1-5 questions from SciFi.SE will be asked during the event, meaning they will get an answer from the brains behind *Futurama*. The users whose questions get asked will receive a *Futurama* prize package including the items listed on the [Rules & Prizes](http://answerama.com/rules-and-prizes) page of Answerama as well as other exclusive items.

The event takes place on Wednesday, July 11th at 10:30 PM EDT/July 12th 2:30 AM UTC after that night's episode airs on Comedy Central. Check out [*Futurama*'s site on Comedy Central](http://www.comedycentral.com/shows/futurama) for the live event and more information.

---

Hope that clears up my previous vagueness! To sum up all the dates involved:

- June 13th: *Futurama* Week begins
- June 20th: *Futurama* premieres on Comedy Central; *Futurama* Week ends
- June 27th: *Futurama* minisite launches
- July 11th: *Futurama* Q&A event!

If you have any questions, you can comment on this post or ping me in chat. Ready your Futurama questions and get ready to post them tomorrow.

Comment: Bender is great!

Comment: We should make the site Futurama themed! And have Math.SE link to us! :D

Comment: Aha! So *this* is why there are so many questions about Futurama being asked.

Comment: ...and why so many are "<joke>.  Why?" :(

Comment: How unfortunate. Not a fan.... And it seems to be generating a lot of junk questions. Was this really a wise idea?

Comment: @aramis I'd rather have a [tag:futurama] week than a [tag:my-little-pony] week.

Comment: Amen to that, brother. My Little Pony?

Comment: From where I sit, MLP is no worse than Futurama. Friendship is Magic, don'chya know? ;) (I have female children...)

Comment: Futurama week has been incredibly annoying... :)

Comment: HEY. MLP:FiM is amazing. You can bite my shiny metal-- *bzzt!*

Comment: Where is the Futurama mini-site? and How will it work? ^_^

Comment: @TheDoctor http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/answerama-the-futurama-mini-site-is-live

Comment: I _like_ Futurama, but I think this was a terrible idea :(

Comment: test [link text](http://www.amazon.com/The-Dispossessed-Ursula-K-Guin/dp/0061054887)