# TV show marathon: Futurama

Tags: discussion, chat-event

Given the [Futurama promotions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1908/futurama-week-event) that are going on, I was curious if anyone would be interested in rewatching Futurama.  It's been a few years since I last watched it from start to finish, and figure this would be a perfect time to do so.  Here in the US, most TV shows have finished their seasons, and the summer TV season hasn't quite begun.  In addition, the show is up on Netflix Instant Streaming, so it's easy for many US folks (and maybe Canadians?) to access the show.

In terms of the plan to watch the show, I'm not aiming to have a synchronized viewing, given the massive scope of the Futurama canon that we'll be working through.  Trying to get a bunch of people organized to watch episodes at the same time would take days/weeks to schedule.  So, what I propose is that people who are interested just watch Futurama and post and answer questions.  I'll be doing the same, my plan is to start at episode 1 and work through all 6 seasons + the 4 movies.  If you're up for just watching a few of your favorite episodes, I encourage you to do so.

I'll be idling in a Futurama chat room that I'll be making shortly.   I hope to chat with other people who are rewatching the show.  I expect us all to be able to quote Futurama and the show's various jokes while we're in there (Scruffy's going to die the way he lived!).  We can use the space to brainstorm questions or hash out the details on answers we're working on.

So, anyone planning on joining me in a rewatch of Futurama?

Answer (score 3):

And a mere month later, I've finished.  This morning I watched the end of 'volume 6' of Futurama, concluding my marathon.

Comment: Interestingly enough this morning I started up a new Futurama marathon for myself...

Comment: @Dason Good news everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I've Seasons 1-4 + films sitting on my shelf, but I've watched them often enough that I learned large parts the dialogue. :)
Anyway, I've been thinking about ordering season 5+6 from amazon.**com** since my local amazon doesn't have the sixth season, but I'm a bit put off by the delivery time and the prospect to have to collect them from customs. But I haven't watched a single episode yet on TV.

A synchronised re-watch by several people doesn't sound doable, but would certainly fuel conversation. If you do plan on watching the whole thing on your own, why not put a schedule of some sort into the chat room, so that other people can join in?

Comment: [I've posted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4938638#4938638) my rough schedule for viewing.  Not promising that I'll be watching at all those times, but that'll give folks an idea as to when I'll be around.