# On flagging and low-quality answers

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

Possibly due to the [*Futurama* event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1908/futurama-week-event), we've had a rash of bad answers by drive-by users recently, especially but by no means exclusively on *Futurama* questions. These answers need curating. There are two means of curating bad answer posts: downvoting and deleting.

- If the answer is **obviously** completely bogus, or if it's something like “I wondered the same”, then please **flag it as “not an answer”**.
- If the answer is bogus, but not obviously so, then **downvote**.

  Keep in mind that moderators are not supposed to use subject knowledge (and at least one of us has no subject knowledge of *Futurama*). *Futurama* has convoluted plots. If it takes research to find out whether a post is an unsubstantiated but plausible theory, or complete tripe, we cannot delete the answer. But if it is tripe, it should be downvoted.

Examples:

- “Boobs... Boobs make you become leader... Yes, Boobs.” (Yes, this is a genuine, complete answer that was posted on this site) → clearly idiotic, flag as “not an answer” (or vote to delete if you have 20k rep).
- [20 lines of implausible plot involving time travel on a *Futurama* question] → on the face of this description, this could be a right answer. Downvote, but don't flag as “not an answer” or “very low quality” — we couldn't act on it.

Again, remember: **moderators do not judge whether answers are correct**.

Please use the right tool to help keep the site clean.

Comment: Gaming had/has a similar problem and has a good writeup [on their meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/on-quality-answers-and-the-task-of-moderators) as well