# Answerama, the Futurama mini-site, is live!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, answerama

[**Answerama**](http://answerama.com/) is live!

Check out the site. Our awesome designer Jin Yang really knocked it out of the park, as did [balpha](http://stackexchange.com/users/40051/balpha) and [Lauren](http://stackexchange.com/users/464232/lauren) on the dev end. Keep an eye out, because later you will see that Balpha made avatars float in a jar! It's a wonder.

---

**How does it work?**

**Answerama** is now home to all of the open questions tagged [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) on the site. We will be awarding **one winner on a daily basis**, every day at 12AM UTC. **How do you win?**

- Each day at 12 AM UTC/8 PM EDT until July 11, one winner will be drawn randomly from the pool of users who have written a question or answer with a minimum score of three that has been posted since the start of Futurama week on June 13th.
- Each question or answer a user has with a minimum score of three will act as one entry into the pool; the more quality questions and answers you write, the bigger chance you have to win
- Must be tagged [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) to be eligible
- Users may only win once
- Question must not be closed
- No bots, no scripts, no multiple accounts, be nice and play fair

More in-depth rules and a run-down of the prizes can be found [here](http://answerama.com/rules-and-prizes). The first winner will be crowned later today, and *your avatar will float in a jar on the main page!*

Enjoy the contest, and ask awesome Futurama questions, and be on the lookout for awesome Futurama questions that you can provide awesome answers for!

Comment: Do the questions need to be posted that day, or is the drawing from all existing >= +3 questions?

Comment: @Keen Edited to clarify; it's any answer or question that has been posted since the start of Futurama Week on June 13th.

Comment: Any news on the QA session?

Comment: Would we get a Head Museum of all winners?

Comment: @DavRob60 They can be viewed here: http://answerama.com/winners I think the link might become more prominent shortly.

Comment: @BrettWhite please see here for an issue that I am having: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2006/3383

Answer (score 2):

It shows all tags, and they all link back here. So a question tagged [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) [time-travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) shows up with both tags (though the first is redundant) and the second tag is a link to all SF&F questions tagged `time-travel`.

Surely it would make more sense to (a) omit the `futurama` tag (and if that leaves many questions showing no tags, what harm?), and (b) have the second tag be a link to all questions tagged both `time-tavel` *and* `futurama`.