# Why are we getting high amount of futurama questions?

Tags: discussion

I should have asked it a long ago... I was wondering what has recently happened in futurama universe?

Comment: Info on this has been posted on the community bulletin for quite some time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the result of publicity by the Futurama folks. See these posts:

[Futurama Week + Q&A Event on July 11th!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1908/3267)
[Answerama, the Futurama mini-site, is live!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1970/3267)
[Possible Futurama Flood Warning, July 2nd](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1990/3267)

In addition, as I understand, the Futurama facebook page mentioned that there would be prizes for Futurama week here and that drove a lot of low-quality questions just hoping for a prize.